# How to deal with the different powers of the same variable here?

Tags: calculus, exponentiation

[image]

In this solution they take out the **ro** to put it on one side of the equation and give it power **6**

How do we take out **ro** as a common when the two **ro**'s have different powers?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the one step after another calculation:

$$ 6Ar_0^{-7} -12Br_0^{-13} = 0$$

$$ 6Ar_0^{-7} = 12Br_0^{-13} $$

$$ Ar_0^{-7} = 2Br_0^{-13} $$

$$ A = 2B*\frac{r_0^{-13}}{r_0^{-7}} $$

$$ A = 2B*(r_0^{-6}) $$

$$ Ar_0^{6} = 2B $$

$$ r_0^{6} = 2B/A $$

$$ r_0 = \sqrt[6](2B/A) $$

And here is an example since the mechanics seems to be unclear:

$$ A*2^{-3} = B*2^{-2} $$

$$ A = B*\frac{2^{-2}}{2^{-3}} $$

$$ A = B*{2^{-2}}*{2^{3}} $$

$$ A = B*2 $$

Answer (score 3):

Factorize:
$$
0 = 6Ar_0^{-7} - 12Br_0^{-13} = 6r_0^{-13} ( Ar_0^6 - 2B )
$$
so $Ar_0^6 = 2B$. I think you can take it from there.

Answer (score 3):

We can write the equation as $$r_0^{-1}(6Ar_0^{-6}-12Br_0^{-12})=0$$ Multiplying both sides by $r_0$ gives $$6Ar_0^{-6}-12Br_0^{-12}=0$$ Now substituting $x=r_0^{-6}$ (notice that $x\neq 0$) yields $$6Ax-12Bx^2=0$$ This we can easily solve, and since $x\neq 0$, we know $x=\frac{6A}{12B}=\frac{A}{2B}$. Now trace back to $r_0$ to obtain $r_0=x^{-1/6}=\left(\frac{A}{2B}\right)^{-1/6}$, so $$r_0=\left(\frac{2B}{A}\right)^{1/6}$$

Hope this helped!

Comment: Nice way to take a straightforward linear problem and turn it into a quadratic. :-)